# How to delivery Salesforce API access in Managed Package when using Lightning Component

Tags: metadata-api, oauth2, tooling-api, oauth, namedcredentials

Trying to build managed package that can analyze metadata configuration, flow specifically. Building as Lightning Component. Looking for a solution to delivery a Named Credential capable of accessing the local Salesforce instance. (Named Credential being the recommended method for API access via Lightning Component, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm)

**Details**

The only way I've found to get the flow information is the metadata or tooling APIs via callout. To access these from apex you must either have a remote site with a valid API-enabled session token or you can use a Named Credential for an OAuth token, or some custom/external OAuth setup.

I have built the package using Named Credential but can't find a way to deliver it cleanly. The Named Credential is for a specific URL so it wouldn't work for all customers. Seems like using a Named Credential for a somewhat dynamic endpoint just isn't going to work or would require significant install effort by the customer.

**Fallback**

Looking to fall back to either building with Visualforce to get an API-enabled session leveraging dynamically installed Remote Site or standing up an external proxy server to relay requests which would provide a consistent URL. The latter would provide an additional hurdle when it comes to SFDC security review but would otherwise provide a method to utilize the recommended Named Credential for access.